# Find supremum and infimum of a given S

Tags: real-analysis

Here is my problem i want to solve and by the way this is one of olympiad problem in my country

$$S=\{\sqrt[3]n - \sqrt[3]m \mid n,m\in\Bbb{N}\}$$
find $\sup(S)$ and $\inf(S)$

i think i have to choose a candidate to be my supremum and show that number is an upper bound of the set. but i cant think any good candidate if i take a look at the set . Any hints to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Fix $m=1$, let $n \rightarrow \infty$. You should be able to obtain your supremum.

Can you handle infimum using similar trick?

Comment: i will try , i think i can handle infimum